# can I buy all plots of land on skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I am thinking of buying the legendary edition for ps3 and I'm interested in heathfire so I've got a quick question.
I am wondering if I can buy all three plots of land in the game.

Comment: One liner - yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can. Buying a piece of land does not preclude you from buying the others.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you have the patience and dedication.
Here's a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-A98Pe-mF0k) that outlines how.